# Symfony - return just one param

Tags: php, mysql, function, symfony

I wrote a code that should  receive one param, number(string)..

My Controller.

```
   /**
 * @Route("/activate", name="activate")
 * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse
 */
public function getActivate()
{
        $data = array(
            'number' => '123456'
        );
        return $this->success($data);
}
```

I dont know is it a better way to write a query function in my service and than call it to my controller or this is the right way. If query is better then how should I start? Like:

```
public function getNumber($data)
{
    $number = $this->getRepository()
        ->createQueryBuilder('n')
        ->select('n')
        ->where('n.data = :data').....
```

Answer (score 1):

No it's not better to place your query inside service.

In general follow atleast these 3 rules:

1) Don't place any bussiness logic and queries in your controller. Controller should only call the service functions

2) Following from point one, services should communicate with repositories.

3) Queries should be located in repositories.

**So Controller->Service->Repository**

*Keep in mind, that sometimes it might be useful to call some repository function from controller (if you don't need additional work with the result of repository function and you can straight return it)*

**Examples of how I work.**

In the following example to achieve this

1) Use Dependency Injection to get the service in your controller
2) Call it

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use AppBundle\Service\MapService;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

/**
 * Class MainPageController
 * @package AppBundle\Controller
 */
class MainPageController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @var EntityManagerInterface
     */
    private $em;

    /**
     * @var MapService
     */
    private $mapService;

    /**
     * MainPageController constructor.
     * @param EntityManagerInterface $em
     * @param MapService $ms
     */
    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em, MapService $ms)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
        $this->mapService = $ms;
    }

    /**
     * @param Request $request
     * @return Response
     */
    public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {
        $mapData = $this->mapService->prepareMapInformation();

        return $this->render('@App/pages/index.html.twig', [
            'mapData' => $mapData,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Second Example - **Service**.

1) Inject your needed repository or inject entity manager inside service and get repository trough it
2) Call needed rep function
3) Do some work with it and return

```
public function prepareMapInformation(): array
{
   $result = [];
   $activeCities = $this->cityRepository->getAllActiveCities();
   $companyInformation = $this->companyRepository
   ->getInformationForMap();

foreach ($activeCities as $oneCity) {
    /** @var City $oneCity */
    $push = [];
    $push['latitude'] = $oneCity->getLatitude();
    $push['longitude'] = $oneCity->getLongitude();
    $push['nameLocation'] = $this->determineNameLocation($oneCity- 
    >getNameLocation());
    $push['companies'] = $this->getCompanies($companyInformation, 
    $oneCity);

    if (!empty($push['companies'])) {
        $result[$oneCity->getName()] = $push;
    }
}

return $result;
}
```

Third example - Repository.

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Repository;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\Expr\Join;

/**
 * Class CityRepository
 * @package AppBundle\Repository
 */
class CityRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function getAllCitiesAssoc(): array
    {
        return $this->_em->createQueryBuilder()
            ->select('c')
            ->from('AppBundle:City', 'c', 'c.name') // third param is index by (it creates assoc array with keys of city names)
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function getAllActiveCities(): array
    {
        return $this->findBy(['active' => 1]);
    }
}
```

**EDIT AFTER @Alister Bulman answer.**

Yeah you can use ParamConverter if you don't need additional logic with your entity and just wan't to return it's data to view. But this is not so nice in cases, you need to do additional logic with the data, because then you must do it in controller or pass the entity to service.

Answer (score 1):

The answer by @revengeance is solid, but I would also add that it will also depend on where the $number is coming from. If it's static, like your example, then passing it into a service is perfectly reasonable.

However, if it's coming from the URL Parameters:

```
/**
 * @Route("/activate/{id}", name="activate")
 * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse
 */
```

then you can Type-Hint the entity with a `ParamConverter`, and a couple already exist to do some things automatically (you can also write your own for other tasks).

```
/**
 * @Route("/activate/{id}", name="activate")
 * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse
 */
public function activateAction(Post $post)
{
    // other security checks - do we have permission to activate this?
    // ....  

    return $this->activatePost($post);  // do something to turn on the entity
}

public function activatePost(Post $post)
{
    $post->setActive(true);
    $post->persist(true);

    return $post;
}
```

Here, a Post entity is found by it's primary key - post.id - and passed fully formed as an object into the controller action, where it can be used.  If there is no such item, the framework throws a 404-Not Found error for you.

Comment: Yeah, paramConverter is nice to economy time and retrieve entity data without service/rep. But it's not so nice in cases you need additional logic with entity data, because then you must do it in controller...